# How to say "keep+ing" in German?

Tags: grammar, style

> Er schreibt ***weiter*** auf Deutsch.
>
> He keeps writing in German
>
> Der Student lernt die Grammatikregeln ***weiter***, bis er sie beherrscht.
>
> The student keeps studying the grammar rules til he memorises them.
>
> Die Bodybuilders müssen ***weiter*** tranieren, damit sie dicker Muskeln haben können.
>
> The Bodybuilders have to keep training to have bigger muscles.

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mögliche Alternativen:

> Die Bodybuilder (kein s!) müssen ihr Training *fortsetzen*, damit ihre Muskeln dicker werden.
>
> Er schreibt *weiterhin* auf Deutsch.

Oder, mit leicht anderem Fokus:

> Der Student lernt *immer noch* die Grammatikregeln.